# Joining array elements with a regex

Tags: jquery, regex, join

Is it possible to join array elements with a regex? If so, how do I achieve these requirements?

- Every element should be joined with a spacing character unless it is an empty element.
- Empty array elements should be joined with a new line character (`\n`).

That means that this:

```
["Hello, this is a sentence.", "This is another sentence.", "", "", "Then, there are 2 new lines.","","Then just one new line."]
```

Should be converted with `.join` to this:

```
Hello, this is a sentence. This is another sentence.

Then, there are 2 new lines.
Then just one new line.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string = "";

for(var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
    var lastElement = elements[index -1];
    string += elements[index] !== "" ? (lastElement && lastElement !== ""? " " + elements[index] : elements[index]) : "\n";
}
console.log(string);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wwJfT/3)**

Comment: almost worked fine. i still don't know why is it adding a space character at the beginning of all sentences.

Comment: @andufo Sorry, I didn't see it. Fixed.

Comment: still has some issues when the sentences are joined without newlines between them, but you gave me the main idea. i'll try to take it from there. thanks!

Comment: i had to accept @kevin-b 's answer, it covered all the spacing issues between sentences as well.

Comment: worked fine this time, with less code. i just had to add a $.trim(string) to get rid of the last space character. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the array replacing empty elements with `<br />` or `\n` depending on where you are using the string, then join it on `""`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    myArr[i] = myArr[i] === "" ? "\n" : myArr[i];
}
var myStr = myArr.join("");
```

Edit: here's a full demo with your additional requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/auAAH/

```
var myArr = ["Hello, this is a sentence.", "This is another sentence.", "", "", "Then, there are 2 new lines.", "", "Then just one new line."];
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    if (myArr[i] === "") {
        myArr[i] = "\n";
        if (i !== 0 && myArr[i - 1] !== "\n") {
            myArr[i - 1] = myArr[i - 1].replace(/ $/, "");
        }
    }
    else if (i < myArr.length-1) {
     myArr[i] = myArr[i] + " ";   
    }
}
var myStr = myArr.join("");
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = myStr​;​
```

Comment: I'm using it on a textarea. I have to join them with a space character, else the sentences will have no spacing between them. I also don't want unnecessary spaces in newlines.

Comment: Either way all of the changes will need to be done in a loop of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

You should first use a match/replace loop to modify the elements according to your rules, and then you should `.join` the resulting array.